# Inner data classes

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

Could someone give me a little pointer on data classes. I'm finding a very steep learning curve with Kotlin, but I'm getting there slowly.

I have a data class of:

```
data class newGame(
    val gamename: String,
    val gamedate: String,
    val players: List<Player>
) {
    data class Player(
        val player: String,
        val player_id: Int,
        val score: Int,
        val points: Int
    )
}
```

I can create an instance of the outer (newGame) class, but I'm struggling to get to grips with how I add Players. I thought I could do something like:

```
var gm: newGame

gm.gamename = GamesList.text.toString()

val p = newGame.Player
p.player = Player1.text.toString()

gm.players.add p
```

But Android Studio says I need a companion object and I'm not sure how that needs to look

The interface looks like:

```
interface CreateGame {
    @POST("new")

    fun addNewGame(
        @Query("operation") operation: String,
        @Body() newGame: newGame
    ): Call<gameEvent>

companion object {

    fun create(): CreateGame {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BaseURL)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(CreateGame::class.java)
    }
}
```

I get how the companion object create() creates the instance of the game, but I can't figure out what I need to write so that I can add players to the inner class.

Could someone give me a pointer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can create an instance of the outer (newGame) class, but I'm
> struggling to get to grips with how I add Players. I thought I could
> do something like:

Well, first understood the terms `val` and `var`. The property `gamename` is val which means its read-only, to write it you have to make it as `var`, same goes to all other properties. and `players` should be `mutableListOf` or `ArrayList<>` type so you can modify it later. `List` is immutable, which means you can't add after initialization.

```
data class newGame(
    var gamename: String,
    var gamedate: String,
    var players: ArrayList<Player>
)
data class Player(
    var player: String,
    var player_id: Int,
    var score: Int,
    var points: Int
)
```

Now In your case, you need to add a secondary constructor OR initialize all properties while declaring as below

```
data class newGame(
    var gamename: String? = null,
    var gamedate: String? = null,
    var players: ArrayList<Player> = ArrayList()
)
data class Player(
    var player: String?=null,
    var player_id: Int?=null,
    var score: Int?=null,
    var points: Int?=0
)
```

In main class

```
    var gm: newGame = newGame()

    gm.gamename = "GamesList.text.toString()"

    val p = Player()
    p.player = "Player1.text.toString()"

    gm.players.add(p)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That was exactly the help I needed. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between nested class and inner class.
A nested class cannot do the same thing as an inner class. An inner class has an implicit reference to its outer class instance. A nested class doesn't.

Comment: OK. So how do I define it as a inner class and have the ability to add players? I thought what I had defined was an inner class

Comment: Do it like this


 class newGame(
    val gamename: String,
    val gamedate: String,
    val players: List<Player>
) {
     class Player(
        val player: String,
        val player_id: Int,
        val score: Int,
        val points: Int
    )
}

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a [nested class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html) and I don't think your use case requires this structure. you can simply move the `Player` class outside the `newGame` class. and then you can create objects of `newGame` as

```
// Create Player objects by passing appropriate values to the constructor
val playerA = Player(player = "A", player_id = 1, score = 50, points = 50)
val playerB = Player(player = "B", player_id = 2, score = 60, points = 80)

// Create a newGame
val newGame = newGame(gamename = "MyGameName", gamedate = "GameDate", players = listOf(playerA, playerB))
```